# DisplayName is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, grid

model:

```
[Display(Name = "Status")]
public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
```

in view:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Users).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions).Columns(column =>
{
    column.For(ulv => ulv.Name);
    column.For(ulv => ulv.SurName);
    column.For(ulv => ulv.IsApproved.Equals(true) ? "Approved" : "Not Approved").Sortable(false);

})
```

Dismplay name "status" - not shows. Column name is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not doing doing `column.For` on the `IsApproved` property, but either on the string `"Approved"` or `"Not Approved"`.

What you need it to add another property to your view model and decorate that instead:

```
public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Status")]
public string IsApprovedString
{
    get { return this.IsApproved ? "Approved" : "Not Approved"; }
}
```